# Adding additional UITabbarItem to UITabbarController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am wondering if there is a way to add an additional `UITabBarItem` to my exisiting `UITabBarController`. It doesn't need to be in runtime.

All I want to do is when hitting this button I want to `presentModalViewController:` over my actually visible ViewController, which should either be the TabBarController or its controllers.

Hopefully this is clear enough, if not, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

As a result of my research you cannot add a UITabBarItem to a UITabBar that is managed by a UITabBarController.

Since you maybe have added your UITabBarItem by adding a list of view controller, this is also the way of your choice to add further custom UITabBarItems, as i will show now:

**Pre-Conditions:** 
As i mentioned before, you maybe have added your UITabBarItems by adding a list of view controller:

```
tabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init]; // tabbarController has to be defined in your header file

FirstViewController *vc1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
vc1.tabBarItem.title = @"First View Controller"; // Let the controller manage the UITabBarItem

SecondViewController *vc2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
vc2.tabBarItem.title = @"Second View Controller";

[tabbarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: vc1, vc2, nil]];

tabbarController.delegate = self; // do not forget to delegate events to our appdelegate
```

**Adding custom UITabBarItems:**
Now since you know how to add UITabBarItems through adding view controller, you can also use the same way to add custom UITabBarItems:

```
UIViewController *tmpController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
tmpController.tabBarItem.title = @"Custom TabBar Item";
// You could also add your custom image:
// tmpController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage alloc]; 
// Define a custom tag (integers or enums only), so you can identify when it gets tapped:
tmpController.tabBarItem.tag = 1;
```

Modify the line above:

```
[tabbarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: vc1, vc2, tmpController, nil]];

[tmpController release]; // do not forget to release the tmpController after adding to the list
```

All fine, now you have your custom button in your TabBar.

**What about handling events of this custom UITabBarItem?**

Its easy, look:

Add the UITabBarControllerDelegate to your AppDelegate class (or the class which is holding the tabbarController).

```
@interface YourAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> { }
```

Fit the protocol definition by adding this function:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)theTabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
  NSUInteger indexOfTab = [theTabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

  UITabBarItem *item = [theTabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:indexOfTab];
  NSLog(@"Tab index = %u (%u), itemtag: %d", indexOfTab, item.tag);  
  switch (item.tag) {
    case 1:
      // Do your stuff
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Now you have all you need to create and handle custom UITabBarItems. 
Hope this helps.
Have fun....

Answer (score 0):

Access the tabBar - property of your UITabBarController ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)), grab the elements array with the `items` - property ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITabBar)), add a new UITabBarItem to this array and use the tabBar's `setItems:animated:` - method to update your tab bar. Add an action to this tab bar to  display the modal view controller.